# remove controllers and actions from URL with MVC routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know this has been asked before but I'm really struggling with the concept of route configs in MVC - specifically removing controller names and/or action names from a URL.

On my webpage, I have a partial view called "Sidebar", which uses its own controller (SidebarController).

Within the sidebar's partial view, I have the following ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("December-2012", "Archive", new { id = "December-2012" })
```

When the link is built, the URL reads as

```
http://localhost/Sidebar/Archive/December-2012
```

My problem is having the "Sidebar" part appearing in the URL - this controller isn't technically *used* for any navigation; it's just used to build the partial view. Instead, I want the URL to read:

```
http://localhost/Archive/December-2012
```

I tried specifying the controller on the ActionLink, but this just results in

```
http://localhost/Archive/Archive/December-2012
```

Could somebody please explain (in simpleton terms) how I configure a route so that when /Archive is put on the end of the URL, it knows to call the ArchiveController with (let's say) the Index(id) action?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for asking a question that's been covered before - as I said I'm just really struggling with the whole concept of route maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entire sure what your doing wrong here. Perhaps also include the code for the second url.

You could use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the Html.ActionLink method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

You would use it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("December-2012(ThisIsLinkText)", "Index", "Archive", 
                 new { id = "December-2012"}, null);
```

Which will produce the following url:

```
http://localhost/Archive/Index/December-2012
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment you need this route above your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ArchiveRoute", 
    "Archive/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Archive", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

And the same action link should map to this url:

```
@Html.ActionLink("December-2012(ThisIsLinkText)", "Index", "Archive", 
                 new { id = "December-2012"}, null);
```

Remember the route has to be above the Default route.

This url should then work:

```
http://localhost/Archive/December-2012
```

Comment: That's pretty close - I'd tried that overload but it creates a new problem, which is having the "Index" action appearing in the URL. Ideally, I'd like to just have /Archive/{id} instead of /Archive/{action}/{id}, and then have the route map "know" that it's got to call the Index(id) action without having it specified in the URL.

Comment: @user1861826 Ah I see. That wasn't very clear from your question.

Comment: Ha-ha! Spot on! Thank you!! I wish I could vote your answer up, but as I've just signed up on the website I don't have the 15 rep required to vote on answers. But that's exactly what I needed (and honestly, now I see it working I wonder why the hell it took me so long to "get it"!)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**, try a blank action for index:

```
@Html.ActionLink("December-2012", "", "Archive", new { id = "December-2012" }, null)
```

> Could somebody please explain (in simpleton terms) how I configure a
>   route so that when /Archive is put on the end of the URL, it knows to
>   call the ArchiveController with (let's say) the Index(id) action?

The default route should be doing this. This is the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

What happens here, is that when you just type your url in `http://localhost/` it runs that route, and notices there's no controller/action specified, so it goes to the default which is "Home", and runs the default action which is "Index".

You could add an `Archive` route (as an example) above the default route in your `RouteConfig` (or `Global.asax` if you're using mvc3):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ArchiveRoute",
                url: "archive/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Archive", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This will fire every time your URL starts like `http://localhost/archive`

Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: The first overload you mention doesn't exist. There is no `Html.ActionLink(this,string,string,string,object)`. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear Thanks for the explanation on routes - helps clear things up. For my first post on this site, I am blown away by how quickly you all respond!